# Untapping with a spell or ability remove summoning sickness?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Basically the title. If I summon a creature, use an ability to "untap" it before my combat step. May I attack with the creature?

Comment: Summoning sickness does not mean the creature is tapped.  "Untapping" a creature that is not tapped will not do anything.

Comment: No. The rule says: "*A creature can't attack unless it has been under its controller's control continuously since his or her most recent turn began.*"

Comment: Also, I find it hard to believe your creature is tapped on the turn it came out. (It's possible, but very rare.)

Comment: @ikegami Not that rare, especially in this brave new world of Vehicles.

Comment: @ikegami Where in the question did the OP say that his creature was tapped?

Comment: @Rainbolt, They said they untapped their creature. For that to happen, it must have been tapped. Maybe they were merely instructed to untap the creature, but I have no reason to believe the OP misspoke. If we discover they did, we can address that error then.

Comment: Usually when someone puts a word in quotes, it's because they are using the word in a way contrary to what it normally means. That indicates to me that the OP's creature was already untapped, and they used an ability to "untap" it. But maybe you're right, and the OP's creature was tapped.

Comment: @Rainbolt, If it's as you say and the OP knows that the instruction to untap didn't do anything, then why would they ask if it did something. Your speculations are not useful.

Comment: Let's continue this discussion [somewhere more appropriate](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65136/discussion-about-untapping-with-a-spell-or-ability-remove-summoning-sickness).